# How to remove Battery ICON in Android Lollipop image by default?

Tags: android, android-source

I want to disable battery icon in the status bar of Android Lollipop 5.0.1 by default during build. Because my device doesn't have battery. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar` class in the SystemUI package and search for battery.